# Ubuntu 18.04 - how can I prevent my display turning off immediately when I lock the screen?

Tags: lock-screen, screensaver

My display turns off when I lock the screen (with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>). This is pretty anoying, because when I want to unlock immediately after that I need to wait like 3 seconds until my screen turns on.

When I lock my laptop I would like to see the lock screen, I don't need my display to turn off.

Please help me to turn this screensaver off or tell where I can find the source code to fix it :)

Comment: This is a common complaint but my phone can't find the duplicate...

Comment: Yeah, but there is no clear answer for that...I really would like to fix it even with chanigng the gnome internals but I have never done anything with linux or gnome source code..

Comment: @VladSpirin isn't that the opposite problem?

Comment: @Zanna Ok......

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/788149/stop-monitor-from-going-to-sleep-in-ubuntu-16-04/788456#788456