# Stop monitor from going to sleep in ubuntu 19.10

Tags: screen, monitor, lock

I'm searching for a new solution to stop monitor going to sleep in ubuntu 19.10 desktop when I lock screen.

This solution with gscreen doesn't work anymore: https://askubuntu.com/a/788456/1020896.

On the energy settings I also configured turn off display: Never.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
```

But maybe someone can confirm if this is the recommended way. I just watch the settings with command below and try something:

```
gsettings list-recursively
```

Answer (score 1):

mine was set as:

```
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled true
```

but see GUI screenshot - was set to false.

entering:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
```

results in:

```
org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay uint32 0
```

also present in `gsettings list-recursively`:

```
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay uint32 0
```

None of this helps. Ditto with nvidia settings, no joy there either.

I eventually have given up and set power manager > display > display power management ON & blank after = 60 minutes.

Which is probably fine for what I need anyway but it still sucks that there are a myriad of places in GUI & terminal which ostensibly control this and none of them work.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: org.gnome.desktop.session absent in 20.04.

Comment: and this above approach (display power off after 60 mins) no longer does anything, screen turns off after 5 minutes.